# Modifying CSS width with Jquery according to screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm running into some problems with the following code.  What I'm trying to do is modify the width of a `div` via `css` according to the width of the screen.

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> // Add JQuery Code.   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="something" style="background-color: black; width: 100px;">hello</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (screen.width = 1024) {
        $(#something).css('width':'200px', 'background-color':'blue');
    }
    elseif (screen.width = 1366) {
        $(#something).css('width':'300px', 'background-color':'blue');
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You condition is wrong `screen.width == somevalue`

Comment: What is the problem here? do you want to know how to get the screen width?

Comment: My first problem is getting the width to compare with the range, and then my second problem is modifying the css to the appropriate definitions.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I finally worked out my final problem which was I had name instead of id in the div command.  I've updated above to help others that may read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems.
The width should be checked with range

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 1366) {
    $('#something').css({ 'width':'300px', 'background-color':'blue' });
  } else if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
    $('#something').css({ 'width':'200px', 'background-color':'blue' });
  }
});
```

Edit:
Combined with window.resize, then I think it'll behave exactly what you want.
But you can also consider using css media query to achieve responsive layout.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
    .my-style {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1366px){
    .my-style {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `>=` makes more sense. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the window's `resize` event, by the way you are assigning the values inside the if statement,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var something = $('#something');
    if ($(this).width() >= 1366) {
        something .css({'width':'200px', 'background-color':'blue'});
    }
    else if ($(this).width() >= 1024) {
        something.css({'width':'300px', 'background-color':'blue'});
    }
  });
});
```

**Note:** your code has lot of syntax errors like passing a *undefined var as selector*, *error with else if* etc.. and as well as i received a downvote for that.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté what about now..?

Comment: It was missing the object's curly braces still but I've fixed it. I didn't DV you btw, anyway +1 for the effort.

Comment: Hmmmmmm for some reason its still not working for me.